# What is the best way to organize my active directory structure

Tags: active-directory, architecture

i would like to adopt the best structure for my active directory domain, in order to be able to apply GPO efficiently.
Here is my schema : CompanyName\ServiceName{Users, Groups, Workstations, Laptops}

My first question is about geographical sites : we have two geographical sites, is it better to create this sort of hierarchy : CompanyName\GeographicalSiteName\ServiceName{Users, Groups, Workstations, Laptops} or handling geographical sites GPO using Sites policy ? Indeed, this organization can lead to have to duplicate some services, if they are split on 2 sites.

My second question is about the {Users, Groups, Workstations, Laptops}, do you think there is better organization ?

Thanks very much

Comment: Unfortunately there is no One True Way to organize Active Directory. The best advice I can give you is to build your domain on paper a couple of different ways, then play with it ("John Doe moves from geographical location 1 to geographical location 2 -- how much trouble does this cause?" ; "Sarah Smith used to work in accounting, but now she's managing part of the production line -- how many changes do I need to make?", etc...) - Pick the least painful design to work with...

Answer (score 3):

This is a very open ended question and a lot of it is determined by your organizations operational methods. Do you work across geographical boundaries a lot or are most things constrained to specific sites?

My personal preference is to create several low level OUs

```
/people
/groups
/services
/hosts
```

People are organized based on Org structure (logically).

Groups are also based on Org structure (contains users, eg "IT-Operations")

Services contain service accounts and 2+ groups for each service (eg "File Server Admins" which would be a member of "File Server Users") which ONLY contain the Org groups. In this case you'd add IT-Operations to File Server Admins and File Server Admins to the Administrators local group on your file servers.

Hosts should contain anything with a IP address that's on the domain (or needs to be represented in AD like printers etc). I break them up geographically since they are physical resources & the Computer GPOs frequently need to respect location.

DNS is aligned with hosts because for instance my file server DFS is "files.***site***.compay.local" and print server "print.***site***.compay.local. Since DHCP generally gives folks the right search suffix even if a user goes to another site they still can print to \print and get to their home directory at \files with out changing anything (assuming DFS-R or something similar to synch homedirs).

Comment: Only, don't _actually_ use `.local` :)